# How do I achieve an average of 60 (or 30, or some other number) FPS without access to vblank?

Tags: c++, windows, frame-rate

How do I achieve an average of say, 60, (or 30) [FPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) in my game without access to the vertical retrace interrupt? (Some drivers don't provide vblank interrupt.)

I don't want to waste CPU time blitting frames faster than the monitor can display anyway, but at the same time I don't want to let the average frame rate drop much lower than the monitor display rate, since that would deprive the player of timely feedback.

I am using OpenGL, but the principle should be the same for GDI or just about anything.
I don't care primarily about avoiding tearing, but rather keeping the illusion of [realtime control](http://www.measurepolis.fi/alma/ALMA%20Human%20Reaction%20Times%20as%20a%20Response%20to%20Delays%20in%20Control%20Systems.pdf), that is the combined input and output lag low.

I am sure there must be some kind of standard pattern for this. (Periodic timers? Sleep?) I am using Windows (pre--Metro) but more generic ideas are very welcome too.

Comment: You are referring to old CRT technology where there was always a consistent vertical blanking phase. Modern display technology that doesn't use electron beams also doesn't have the same concept of "vertical blanking", so this wouldn't be a suitable time reference.

Comment: You can find [some solutions](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=framerate+fps) to similar problems on the gamedev site, where the question is more common.

Comment: @GregHewgill, that is a common misconception. The terminology is old, the concept is still alive. "Even though the typical LCD monitors of today are locked at 60 Hz" quoth http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate

Comment: Ok, I'll counter your Wikipedia link with another. ["Usually no refresh-rate flicker, as the LCD panel itself is usually refreshed at 200 Hz or more, regardless of the source refresh rate."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal_display)

Comment: Refresh rate flicker has nothing to do with tearing artifacts.  Tearing is very much still a problem with LCD monitors.  All the ones I've ever used anyway.

Comment: @GregHewgill, are you splitting hairs? I just want the game to output a new frame to a close average of 1/60th of a second.

Comment: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/  <-- good resource I found the other night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment you added made it more explicit that you are concerned about tearing: Obviously you should use double buffering which you activate when you call `ChoosePixelFormat()` but you still have to get the timing right to have no tearing:

- redraw immediately after your call to `SwapBuffers()`. This gives you 1/60th second; if you need more you have to drop down to eg 30fps temporarily.
- you CAN call the next SwapBuffers immediately, but if you do that you would consume 100% cpu, because as of point 1 you should redraw the backbuffer immediately after it. To avoid it you should *try* to sleep if enough time remains, eg use `QueryPerformanceCounter/Frequency` to determine how much time is left until the next 1/60th second: if it is more than eg 8 millis then `Sleep(1)`, else busy-wait to not make the framerate vary too much.

Comment: Because you cannot be sure how long `Sleep(1)` actually sleeps, especially because the windows scheduler runs other threads while your's sleeps. the 8 ms was chosen in our previous application because it balanced the windows scheduler's granularity vs. the time we needed to render (while still allowing sleep).

Comment: Wow, so I got some real-world heuristics here for free, thanks! :-)

Comment: I don't understand how you came to the conclusion that I am concerned about tearing though.

Comment: Because tearing is the most annoying rendering artifact, your question is about timing and good timing is the only way to get rid of tearing.

Comment: By that logic: The most annoying thing about Santa is his big white beard, my question is about *scissors*, the only way to get rid of beards is scissors, therefore my question is about *Santa*. Don't you think that is a tiny bit circular? :-)   --- (And who gets to decide that tearing is *the* most annoying rendering artifact anyway?)

Comment: If you want to set your priority on something else that is fine with me.